# Why compile error 28 Conversion from 'String' to 'Integer' cannot occur in a constant expression

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, enums, typeconverter

In Statement.

```
Public Enum FileType
    FileWord = "1"
    FileExcel = "2"
End Enum
```

It work on visual basic 2008 and have not error. But I convert to Visual Studio 2012.
It has compile error -> Error 28 Conversion from 'String' to 'Integer' cannot occur in a constant expression.

Comment: Why not just do `1`?  Why are you doing `"1"`?

Comment: Because I want to return value with String.

Comment: Enums aren't strings.